# How to change the color of the text in the Chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I use the Chart.js library to create the graph and its 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js' plugin. My question here is how to change the color of the values ​​on the graph, since I cannot use CSS styles because it is rendered as an image
[image: Chart.js]

Comment: Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Comment: In the documentation I only see the change in the background of the graph and its border, but not of its text

Comment: What about the Fonts section? This might be more inline with what you're looking for: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Comment: Yes using the documentation in the link above , u can use the backgroundColor option in the datasets array. Set the color to whatever u like. U can also use hexcode etc. Font color can also be changed as well.

Comment: Use the 'fontColor' property of the previous link and only change the color of the upper labels, but not the numbers that are on the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the label colour is literally the [first example in the plugin documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/getting-started.html#configuration).

Here's a snippet showing changing the colour for all datasets in a chart:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 2, 4, 8]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really downloaded the plugin without knowing that I had a page with documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library `patternomaly`.

Example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [45, 25, 20, 10],
      backgroundColor: [
        pattern.draw('square', '#ff6384'),
        pattern.draw('circle', '#36a2eb'),
        pattern.draw('diamond', '#cc65fe'),
        pattern.draw('triangle', '#ffce56')
      ]
    }],
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Yellow']
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/patternomaly@1.3.2/dist/patternomaly.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Documentation:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html

Comment: This would change the background colour, not the foreground.